# Etymology of to muckle on to something

Tags: etymology

MANY years ago in the 1960s, a middle-aged friend of mine from England, used the expression that he'd muckled on to something. Meaning that he'd grabbed it like a bulldog. Anyone have any idea of where that came from?

Comment: The usage you mention is illustrated in UD: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Muckle

Comment: He’d grabbed it like a bulldog? So, with his teeth, then? Bulldogs don’t have opposable thumbs to _grab_ things with…

Comment: Related: [What is the meaning of “Many a mickle makes a muckle”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26765/what-is-the-meaning-of-many-a-mickle-makes-a-muckle)

Comment: "Muckle" has a variety of meanings, mainly in Scotland and the north of England. See [urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Muckle)

Comment: It looks like one of the common usages of the word in Scots is as "muckle-moued" (muckle-mouthed), or mickle-mouthed, meaning "big-mouthed". http://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/muckle

Comment: For etymology of muckle/mickle, see https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/micel

Comment: Not sure that I've ever heard this, in the US Midwest.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a regional, AmE usage:

***[Muckle](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/muckle)***:

> To grab on to an object, usually with a great deal of force. May also be used figuratively to indicate a strong attraction for an object or person. Ex: "When I saw her down the bar, I muckled right on to her." ***Origin: Downeast Maine.***

(Online slang dictionary)

[Muckle](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/muckle)

> (US, dialectal) To latch onto something with the mouth.
>
> From: 1954, Elizabeth Ogilvie, The Dawning of the Day‎, page 199:
>
> - *And how'd she get such a holt on you, Terence Campion, let alone the way she's muckled onto those Bennetts?*

(Wiktionary)

Comment: There are some attestations on the Wiktionary entry, too. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/muckle

Comment: Despite Wiktionary’s categorisation, it would appear not to be exclusively American, given that the person whose usage of the word apparently triggered the question was English.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - OP sludge probably give more details about who used the term, in any case  the scottish usage doesn’t have this connotation, which appears to have evolved in America. https://www.alphadictionary.com/bb/viewtopic.php?t=6578